# storage link not loading image after symlink Laravel

Tags: laravel, file-upload

**This is the code to upload an image in my controller and its uploading but the link to view the image is broken**

```php
if (request()->hasFile('payslip')) {
    $payslip = request()->file('payslip')->getClientOriginalName();
    request()->file('payslip')->storeAs('payslip', $user->id . '/' . $payslip, '');
    $user->update(['payslip' => $payslip]);
}
```

**Below is the code in my view**

```html
<img src="{{asset ('payslip/'.Auth::user()->id.'/'. Auth::user()->payslip) }}" alt="payslip" class="credential-img">
```

Comment: what did you set as the default disk? because public is not the default

Comment: it was local...i set public to see if that will work

Answer (score 0):

**Solved the problem

This is the code in my Register Controller to upload image into public folder**

```php
    protected function create(array $data){

        
   
        $user =  User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'cellno' => $data['cellno'],
            'workno' => $data['workno'],
            'address' => $data['address'],

            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            
        ]);
    
        if (request()->hasFile('payslip')) {
            $file = request()->file('payslip');
    //            dd($file);
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = $user->name . $user->email . '_' . $user->id . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move('img/'.$user->id.'/', $filename);
            $user->payslip= $filename;
            $user->save();
        }
    
    return $user;

}
```

**Below is the code in my view**

```html
    <img src="{{asset ('img/'.Auth::user()->id.'/'. Auth::user()->payslip) }}" 
    alt="payslip" class="credential-img">
```